# How to use viewstate values of one function in another function

Tags: asp.net

I have 2 functions. In one function I have 2 viewstate values to get the direction
and sort order. Now I want to use this in another function.

I tried like this:

```
Session["a"] = Viewstate["a"];
Session["b"] = Viewstate["b"];
```

But it is returning NULL values:

```
private string SortDirection(string column)
{
    string sortDirection = WebConstants.SortDirection.Ascending.ToString();
    string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

    if (sortExpression != null)
    {
        if (sortExpression == column)
        {
            string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
            if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == WebConstants.SortDirection.Ascending.ToString()))
            {
                sortDirection = WebConstants.SortDirection.Descending.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
    ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

    return sortDirection;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using viewstate on same page or some other page.If same page post your complete code.

Comment: Yes I want to use those viewstate values in the same page but in Page load. Through those viewstate values I will get sort direction and column name.Help!!!

Comment: can you post your `page_load` code.